# Has_One through a model when the model has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, relationship

I'm trying to set up a system where my Billing Profile can hold an Address and Payment Method through a User. With addresses, it works fine since User only has one but with Payment Method, since User has_many, I keep getting the error:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: 
Could not find the source association(s) :payment_method_id in model User. 
Try 'has_many :payment_method, :through => :user, :source => <name>'. 
Is it one of :address, :billing_profile, or :payment_methods?**
```

**BillingProfile**

```
class BillingProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user, :payment_method
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :address, :through => :user
  has_one :payment_method, :through => :user
end
```

**User**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  has_one :billing_profile

  has_many :payment_methods

  has_one :address, :as => :addressable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end
```

**Address**

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true

  attr_accessible :city, :country, :state, :street_line_1, :street_line_2, :zip_code
end
```

**PaymentMethod**

```
class PaymentMethod < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :is_default

  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :user_id
end
```

**BillingProfile Table**

```
create_table :billing_profiles do |t|
  t.integer :user_id
  t.integer :payment_method_id
  t.timestamps
 end
```

Any idea how if this is even possible or if there is a better way to approach it? I have dabbled in the idea of just manually setting the id's when I create the Billing Profile but then I'd have to create methods to get the payment method which is not terrible but it'd be nice if Rails was able to do it for me.

**EDIT**

So since it appears that what I hoped for is not possible. I simple added a method to Billing Profile to simulate the association.

```
def payment_method
    PaymentMethod.find(payment_method_id)
  end
```

Comment: you need to use `has_one :payment_method`. To keep the consistency (the payment method should be the same then the user) you can use a custom validation method.

Comment: That wouldn't really work because then when you run a query for it, it would look in the PaymentMethods table for a billing_profile_id, which doesn't exist. I want to have the association without adding that column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:through` option is there to link relationships. So, the following hold true:

```
billing_profile.user.address == biling_profile.address
```

However, the following can't be true (because you want only one in one side and a list in the other):

```
billing_profile.user.payment_methods == billing_profile.payment_method
```

You need an extra column to make this relationship. You can only use the `:through` relationship if both returns the same, because there is no "extra memory" to hold only one from a list.

So, in short, you need to add a `has_one` or a `belong_to` without `:trhough` and add a new column (extra memory) to hold this relationship.

Comment: if not clear yet, please ask me and I can try to write a bit more, but right now I couldn't find a better way to explain.

Comment: Alas, that's what I feared. I was hoping for some hidden rails magic :P

Comment: @justNeph Sorry, out of spells today :-)